# How to preserve `atexit` registered exit handlers through `exec` call in C?

Tags: c, linux, exec, atexit

Is there a way to do something similar to `atexit`, but preserve exit handlers after an `exec` call?

Or otherwise is there a way to register exit handlers for another process by process id?

Comment: What needs to be handled?

Comment: Ideally, a parent process forks and the child sets up an exit handler before calling `exec`. Then when the child is about to exit the new program, it calls the exit handler which signals the parent and wait for the parent to inspect the memory of the child. I don't have control of what is being `exec`d, so I can't modify that program.

Comment: Basically, no.  exec always replaces all of the program's memory mappings, leaving nothing.  If you feel you must do this, you could put your handler in a small shared library, and cause the executed program to `LD_PRELOAD` it.  But this is a hack and before considering it, you should think long and hard about why you want to do this, and whether it is the right solution to your underlying problem.  Your question sounds very much like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @nevets: Per your comment above, I think the right way to do this is with `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT`.  You have the child `PTRACE_TRACEME` before exec'ing, and then the parent continues it with `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT`, so that just before exit, the parent gets a chance to ptrace the child and inspect it some more.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's exactly what I want I think! I am already using ptrace, don't know how I missed `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT`. Thanks! Going to try to see if that works, but tentatively I think that's what I'm looking for

Comment: The executed process will not, in general, contain the functions registered with `atexit()` by the executing process.  So there is no way to retain the `atexit()` handlers.

Comment: The parent can call waitpid() on the child, then do what appropriate. But without access to the died child memory.

Comment: @ulix: Right, and that's the reason for having `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT`: the process gets stopped while it is still alive, instead of after it is already a zombie.

Comment: @NateEldredge According to the man page there's nothing the tracer can do to avoid the tracee exiting once `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT` occurs. Is there a way to overwrite the registers (including instruction register) and stack and other memory regions to escape the exit and revert to a previous state?

Comment: @nevets: I don't know, but the man page seems pretty unequivocal that you cannot.